# Change anchor text color when div is hovered - CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have a clickable div and within that div is link.  When the link is hovered the text changes via css a:hover. For some reason I can seem to figure out to apply that hover to the whole div.  Here is my code.

JQuery for making the div clickable:

```
$("div.clickable").click(
function()
{
    window.location = $(this).attr("url");
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="clickable" url="/galleries/Current_exhibits.aspx">
<p><a href="URL">TEST</a></p>
</div>
```

I'd like to add a simple a:hover {color: #000;} effect to the whole div but am having trouble.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just apply `:hover` to the div:

```
.clickable:hover,
.clickable:hover a:link
{
    color: #000;
}
```

I applied it to the link as well, as you'll likely have to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/M3fw2/